# My computer freezes at random times, what information can I get to fix this?

Tags: debian, freeze

At certain random times, though often when a browser is open, which I think is a coincidence because I have the browser open alot the computer will completely freeze up, I can't move the mouse, type or anything. Also I'm using debian buster but the computer also froze on debian stretch.

I've looked at the /var/log/messages logs and found some errors, don't know if they are related:

```
Apr 18 01:51:10 mastergamer kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed

Apr 18 01:51:10 mastergamer kernel: [    1.284126] nouveau 0000:0c:00.0: Direct firmware load for nvidia/gp104/gr/sw_nonctx.bin failed with error -2

Apr 18 01:51:10 mastergamer kernel: [   12.958378] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

Apr 18 01:51:10 mastergamer kernel: [   13.120893] ccp 0000:11:00.2: psp initialization failed

Apr 18 01:51:10 mastergamer udisksd[700]: failed to load module mdraid: libbd_mdraid.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Apr 18 01:51:10 mastergamer udisksd[700]: Failed to load the 'mdraid' libblockdev plugin


Apr 18 01:51:19 mastergamer org.kde.KScreen[1471]: kscreen.xcb.helper: Event Error:  147

This is the last thing I saw on the log.

Apr 18 01:51:24 mastergamer NetworkManager[698]: <info>  [1555573884.1809] agent-manager: req[0x55c42c5680b0, :1.46/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1000]: agent registered
```

**Where could I look to start fixing this problem?**

Comment: Is there any **specific** Unix question for a Unix forum here?

Comment: The `EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro` message could be a hint. I have an openSUSE Laptop with an external SSD for some data. Attaching it to the USB 3.0 port causes read-only remounts from time to time. I don't really know the reason (yet), but I can only use USB 2 ports with that SSD. So it could be a driver problem. Some systems support to disable the super-speed functions, my laptop doesn't. I would suggest to look for more information regarding "super speed". Is your installation on a SSD or NVMe?

Comment: It's installed on an ssd, though it isn't an external ssd. I do have an external hdd. Though I use that for backup data, no system stuff.

Comment: I would check if your computer supports SSD drives. Can you check your syslog for messages containing "xhci_hcd"?

Comment: I found out that the cpu was causing the problem. I used a amd cpu and some of those require c6 state to be disabled to stop this problem. I disabled it in the bios settings and things have seemed to work afterwards.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is still happening, though the cpu was causing problems, I think there is a different problem as well.